# Rails two controller in one form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, geocoding

I am wondering if its possible to keep the relationship and build two controllers in the same time?

Let me explain I have two models and the relationship is has follow:

```
Users, Locations
Users has many locations
Locations belongs_to users
```

I am not sure if I should add virtual field, and if so how, to the users form when creating a new user and then send longitude and latitude attribute as parameters in order to do following in my controller:

`UserController#new`

```
@users= User.new
@location = User.locations.build(params[:latitude,:longitude])
...
```

Here are my two questions:

1. Is this the right approach?
2. How do I create virtual field/hidden field used only for this time only.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write attr_accessor :latitude, :longitude in Location model.

attr_accessor makes reader and writer methods for Model/class objects

Comment: Just out of curiosity, by doing building and using attr_accessor i can still keep the relationship right?